# Express the following complex numbers in standard form

Tags: complex-numbers

$$\left(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)^{25}$$
I know that you have to put it in the form $\cos\theta+i\sin \theta$ but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying De-moivre's theorem,   $(\cos\theta+i\sin \theta)^n=\cos n\theta+i\sin n\theta$
hence, $$\left(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)^{25}$$
$$=\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{6}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^{25}$$
$$=\cos\frac{25\pi}{6}+i\sin\frac{25\pi}{6}$$
$$=\cos\left(4\pi+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)+i\sin\left(4\pi+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)$$
$$=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)$$
$$=\color{red}{\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}+\frac{i}{2}}$$

Comment: okay i understand how you got to root3/2 + i/2 but i still don't understand how you went from 25pi/6 back to pi/6. what happen to the 25?

Comment: You use that fact that $\cos$ and $\sin$ are both cyclic. And Harish has given it in what is essentially standard form. If you want to be really nit-picky you can write it as $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + i \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: that makes sense! thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

When you want to raise a number to an integer power, the polar form is very handy. When in doubt, draw a picture-plot $\frac {\sqrt 3}2+\frac i2$. You should notice that the radius is about $1$.  Do you know how to compute the radius and find it is exactly $1$?  Then you should know that $(re^{i\theta})^n=r^ne^{in\theta}$  You should recognize the angle.